# FileTransfer is not defined error in PhoneGap app

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm having some weird troubles with cordova's FileTransfer function, and think is related to jQueryMobile framework.

I'm using PhoneGap 2.9.0 and jQueryMobile 1.4. I want the app to download a file when the user presses a button, but I get the error "FileTransfer is not defined". Call to the function which downloads the file is as follows:

```
$(document).on( "pageinit", "#download-page", function( e ) {        
    $("#downloadBtn").click(BeginDownload);
});

function BeginDownload() 
{    
    $.mobile.loading( 'show', {
        text: 'Downloading file',
        textVisible: true,
        theme: 'a',
        html: ""
    });    

var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.download(
    "http://mydomain.com/myfile.mp3",
    DownloadOK, DownloadKO);
```

}

But if I call the function BeginDownload from inside deviceready event, everything works fine and file gets downloaded:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", init, false);
function init()
{
    BeginDownload();
}
```

The trouble is that the button for downloading the file is not in the main page. It is in another page the user has to navigate to, so when deviceready event gets fired, the button is not present and I can't bind the event listener.

What am I doing wrong? How can I download a file from a page that is not the main one?

Thanks.